# BigCommerce 404 error when I try to access product that is "not visible" on the Storefront

Tags: bigcommerce

I currently have a few products that are "not visible" on the storefront. I don't want the products to be showcased (appear on the landing page or in the "see all products" page, but I would like to have it be visible when users try to access it directly, for example if a friend shares a link of that product.

But currently when I try to share the link to a product that is "not visible" to my friend, he gets a 404 page not found error, I would like for him to see the product, even though it is not publicly visible, any idea how I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a product is set to be not visible, it will not show for anyone (except for those logged in to the admin panel) on the front end. You can try appending the query string "?showHidden=true" to the end of the URL you are sending your friends. This may allow them to view the product.

Otherwise, you would need to make the product visible and write some custom code to hide it from the general users, or use customer group visibility settings.

**Edit to describe the process of using customer groups:**

The simplest approach here might be the following:

1. Have your friend create a customer account on your store.
2. Assign them to a new customer group (see [documentation here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Customer-Groups)).
3. Add your hidden product to a new category.
4. Make sure the custom customer group has visibility to all categories, while the default customer group has access to select categories (check all except the new category with the hidden product)

As long as your friend is logged in to their customer account, they should be able to see the product, while your normal shoppers cannot! The one major downside to this is if you make any new categories, they will not automatically be visible to your default customer group, and you will have to manually add the visibility.

Comment: Is it possible to add those products to a category for example: "hidden_but_accessible" and make that entire category not visible on the storefront, but still accessible using the link?

Comment: Also is it possible to set so that only certain users can see certain products?

Comment: I have edited my post to describe a solution that might work for you. Unfortunately, I can't think of a better way, without adding a lot of custom code to the theme.